# Javascript: How do I output certain information from an array using fetch?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

So I'm doing a Javascript technical exercise and I have it almost complete, I'm trying to output data from an API url and displaying it on my html page.

I have everything mostly how I want however I cannot display the title from the api that says `Keep What You Want` from `stepNumber`.

I only need `stepNumber` `3` to display `Keep What You Want` instead of `Keep What You Like`.

How do I do that with my current code?

Javascript

```
fetch('https://uqnzta2geb.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/FrontEndCodeChallenge')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        appendData(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('This is an error', err);
    });

function appendData(data) {
    let mainContainer = document.getElementById("testdata");
    let titleContainer = document.getElementById("testdata");
    let bodyContainer = document.getElementById("testdata");


    data
    .filter(item => ["1", "2", "3", "4"].includes(item.stepNumber))
    .sort((a, b) => +a.stepNumber - b.stepNumber)
    .forEach(({id, stepNumber, versionContent}) => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        const divTwo = document.createElement("span");
        const divThree = document.createElement("p");

        const {title, body} = versionContent.slice().pop();

        div.innerHTML = stepNumber;
        divTwo.innerHTML = versionContent[0].title;
        divThree.innerHTML = body;


        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        titleContainer.appendChild(divTwo);
        bodyContainer.appendChild(divThree);
    });

}
```

Comment: Try to use JSON library !

Comment: Under `"stepNumber":3`, you have 3 elements in `versionContent`, "Keep What You Like", "Keep What You Want" and "Keep Everything". You seem to work with its first element only, the crazy `versionContent.slice().pop()` and `versionContent[0]` both do that. If you want to see the 2nd and 3rd elements too, a `versionConent.forEach()` loop could do that instead.

Comment: @tevemadar For `"stepNumber":3`I only need to display `Keep What You Want`. Should I get rid of the `forLoop`?

Comment: You can hardcode some nasty hack, like `divTwo.innerHTML = versionContent[stepNumber==3?1:0].title;`, but it is unclear why would you need that one particular element out of the three.

Comment: @tevemadar it's a technical exercise so they want us to display specific information from the API. Thank you. Is there any good websites or tutorials you know of that I can look at?

Comment: What makes "Keep What You Want" better than "Keep What You Like" and "Keep Everything"? There either has to be a criteria, or your task might be to display all 3 of them.

Comment: @tevemadar That's what they want for the technical exercise to match the mockup I was given.